# Amazon Cart integration with Inline Checkout

Tags: e-commerce, checkout, shopping-cart

I am using amazon checkout cart (with amazon fulfillment). I want to integrate inline checkout with amazon cart. I can't find any documentation to integrate both.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today, I got response from amazon, that it is not at all possible:

> I'm afraid you cannot integrate the two services, since Amazon
>   Shopping Cart uses an older version of Checkout By Amazon than Inline
>   Checkout uses. We recommend that you create a cart yourself and
>   integrate through Standard Checkout or Inline Checkout.